# A question of a video of real analysis: prove that $\overline A$ is closed.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6zs_PTUfKAk

[At 18.40](https://youtu.be/6zs_PTUfKAk?t=1120) Quote: If $q$ is not in $A$ then $q$ is in $A'$: $q$ is a limit point of $A$.
Why is this the case? (This proof doesn't involve $A$ complement).

Proof:
Consider $p$, a limit point of $A$:

If $p$ is in $A$, $p$ is in $\overline A$.

If $p$ is not in $A$, consider $q$ in $N(p)$.
Then $q$ is in $A$, $p$ is a limit point hence in $\overline A$.

If $q$ is not in $A$, then $q$ is a limit point of $A$ (WHY???), consider $N(q)$ contained by $N(p)$.
It contains a point belonging to $N$. Since it belongs to $A$ as well, $p$ is a limit point of $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, $p$ is not a limit point of $A$. It is a limit point of $\overline A$. We then want to show that it's actually *in* $\overline A$, because that shows that $\overline A$ is closed: the definition of a closed set (for this lecturer) is a set which contains all its limit points.

If $p$ is in $A$ then of course it's in $\overline A$, and we're done. So assume $p$ isn't in $A$. Then we need to show $p$ is a limit point of $A$.

The lecturer now considers a neighborhood of $p$ (we're going to look for an element of $A$ in this neighborhood, since to show $p$ is a limit point of $A$ we need one such element in every neighborhood). It must contain a point $q$ in $\overline A$ (because $p$ is a limit point pf $\overline A$). In $\overline A$, not in $A$! The way you've written it is seems as though it's being claimed that $q$ is any point of the neighborhood of $p$, and that any such point is in $A$. That's not what he said!

Now if $q\in \overline A$, it follows from the definition of the closure that either $q$ is in $A$, or $q$ is a limit point of $A$. If $q$ is in $A$, we're done - we have our element of $A$ in the neighborhood of $p$. If $q$ is not in $A$, then it must be a limit point of $A$. So take a neighborhood of $q$ nested inside the neighborhood of $p$. Since $q$ is a limit point of $A$, it must have an element of $A$ in that neighborhood, and that element will also be in the original neighborhood of $p$, as desired.

Comment: Thank you so much! This has been confused me for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

You should note that cl(A) is, by definition, the arbitrary intersection of all the closed sets that contains A. You can easily prove that the arbitrary intersection of closed sets is a closed set (proving that its complement is open). So, makes sense when we say that cl(A) is the "smallest" closed set that contains A. That is, if B is a closed set such that B contains A, then B also contains cl(A).